# Error: grouping factors must have > 1 sampled level

Tags: r, linear-regression

I want to fit a model to obtain the variance due to pH for different bacterial strains. First I have removed NA values and the results associated with pH = 4.5 because they give an error. I have checked that up to this point `data_strain <- subset(results, strain == element)` has selected the data correctly, obtaining a data frame for each strain with its corresponding pH and mu (growth parameter) values. However, when I adjust the model I get the following error: `Error: grouping factors must have > 1 sampled level`. I have searched for information and the only thing I have found is that I should readjust my levels, but I have not been able to solve it. Do you have any idea?

This is the code:

```
resultados <- read_excel("resultados.xlsx")


resultados <- na.omit(resultados[, c("pH", "mu", "cepa")])
resultados <- subset(resultados, resultados$pH != 4.5)

resultados$pH <- as.factor(resultados$pH)

resultados <- resultados %>%
  group_by(cepa) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  ungroup()

niveles <- unique(resultados$cepa)

resultado_modelo <- lapply(niveles, function(elemento) {

  datos_cepa <- subset(resultados, cepa == elemento)

 # # Modelo mixto para la cepa actual
 #  modelo <- lmer(mu ~ pH + (1|cepa), data = datos_cepa)


 #  # Puedes devolver el modelo si lo necesitas
 #  return(summary(resultado_modelo))
 modelo
})
```

This is part of the output from resultados:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  pH       mu cepa    
  <fct> <dbl> <chr>   
1 7.5   0.492 DPC 1375
2 7.5   0.504 DPC 1377
3 7.5   0.514 DPC 1376
4 7.5   0.466 DPC 1378
5 7.5   0.489 DPC 5073
6 5     0.35  APC 1372
```

I expect to fit a mix models for each strain but I keep getting the same error

Comment: By design, you are selecting only a single value of `cepas` for each run of the model. This doesn't make any sense if you want to include `cepas` as a random effect in a mixed effects model. The whole point of a mixed model is to account for the variance introduced by a random effect. In your case, there is only a single level of `cepas` at a time, so there is no variance accounted for by it. If you want a single mixed model, don't use `lapply` at all - you should use `modelo <- lmer(mu ~ pH + (1|cepa), data = resultados)` on your whole data frame.

Comment: If you want to model separately for each strain, then remove the `(1|cepas)` term. But then it is a simple linear regression, not a mixed model.

Comment: you are right. It makes no sense to include 'cepas' as a random effect if I am subseting the data by each 'cepa'. I will do it for the whole data set. Thanks